# How to decorate a function and get a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-class

I am trying to decorate a function and make the decorator convert it into a class.

I currently have a class like this:

```py
class Licht(BaseCore):
    topics = ["glados/tcs/licht/set"]

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, topic, payload):
        mqtt_publish("tcs/bus/cmd", "1200")
```

and I try to decorate it, so that it looks nicer:

```py
@core_factory(["glados/tcs/licht/set"])
def Licht(topic, payload):
    mqtt_publish("tcs/bus/cmd", "1200")
```

This is my current decorator code which doesn't work:

```py
def core_factory(topics):
    class NewCore(BaseCore):
        topics = topics
    def inner(func):
        import types
        NewCore.run = types.MethodType(lambda cls, topic, payload: func(topic, payload), BaseCore)
        return NewCore
    return inner
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: And by doesn't work you mean...? Also, if you decorate a function, what you return should still be a function, or at least a *callable* object, does `BaseCore` implement a `__call__`? I.e. are `BaseCore` instances callable? If not, this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I get a `topics = topics
NameError: name 'topics' is not defined`. But no - the `BaseCore` doesn't implement that.

Comment: `NewCore.run = types.MethodType(lambda cls, topic, payload: func(topic, payload), BaseCore)`**no**. `MethodType` objects *do not belong to the class*. It should be just a plain function-object*, or else it *won't work*

Comment: It wouldn't work for unless I would convert it to MethodType (see https://pastebin.com/daB1KGc7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator should return a function that takes the decorated function and creates a class whose `run` method just calls the decorated function.

```
def core_factory(topics):
    def wrapper(f):

        class _(BaseCore):
            @classmethod
            def run(cls, topic, payload):
                return f(topic, payload)

        _.topics = topics
        _.__name__ = f.__name__

        return _
    return wrapper

@core_factory(["glados/tcs/licht/set"])
def Licht(topic, payload):
    mqtt_publish("tcs/bus/cmd", "1200")
```

Comment: Thanks. I also overwrote `_.__qualname__` and `_.__module__` with the values from the decorated function, as they are very visible in my project.

Comment: One thing I could have done is use `functools.wrap`; I don't recall if it does more than copy the name over.